# Send Parameters in custom attribute in ASP.NET Core 6 Web API

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-webapi

I created a `TypeFilterAttribute`. This filter runs in any case, even if it is not on the method. I do not want this

```
public class RTProAuthorizationHubFilter : TypeFilterAttribute, IHubFilter
{
    public RTProAuthorizationHubFilter(bool isAuthorization = true, Type type = null) :
        base(type ?? typeof(RTProAuthorizationHubContext))
    {
        Arguments = new object[] { isAuthorization };
    }
}
```

`RTProAuthorizationHubContext` class is:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class RTProAuthorizationHubContext : AuthorizeAttribute, IHubFilter
{
    private readonly ISecurityService _securityService;
    private readonly IRTProAuthenticationService _rTProAuthenticationService;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private readonly IOptions<AuthenticationSettingsInfo> _authenticationSettings;
    private bool _isAuthorization

    public RTProAuthorizationHubContext(
        bool isAuthorization,
        ISecurityService securityService,
        IRTProAuthenticationService rTProAuthenticationService,
        IUnitOfWork unitOfWork,
        IOptions<AuthenticationSettingsInfo> authenticationSettings
    )
    {
        _isAuthorization = isAuthorization;
        _rTProAuthenticationService = rTProAuthenticationService;
        _authenticationSettings = authenticationSettings;
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _securityService = securityService;
    }

    public async ValueTask<object> InvokeMethodAsync(
        HubInvocationContext invocationContext, Func<HubInvocationContext, ValueTask<object>> next)
    {
        // ....
    }
}
```

And in `Program` file, I have:

```
builder.Services.AddSignalR(hubOptions =>
{
    hubOptions.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
    hubOptions.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
    hubOptions.AddFilter<RTProAuthorizationHubFilter>();
    //hubOptions.AddFilter(typeof(RTProAuthorizationHubContext));   
});
```

I can not set `isAuthorization` in `RTProAuthorizationHubFilter`.

Please help me

Thanks

Comment: what does `I can not set isAuthorization` mean? can you explain in more detail？

Comment: isAuthorization is a property that I want to value.Consider a custom property

Comment: Do you want to set the value before inject into `RTProAuthorizationHubContext `?

Comment: I wanna fill isAuthorization value on RTProAuthorizationHubFilter